# Similar Questions Glitch

Tags: bug

I was in the process of asking a question on the main Sci-Fi stack when the Similar Questions section started glitching out, rendering it an almost illegible mess. Can you please fix this?

[image]

Comment: (1) Upload your picture to the site instead of linking to it ([edit] your post, then click the Image button), (2) consider posting this on https://meta.stackexchange.com since you need an SE developer to "fix" a problem like this, and such a dev is more likely to see it on main meta rather than here. I can migrate this to main meta if you'd like.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't know how to upload an image that way. Failed to upload image; an error occured on the server. Also, feel free to migrate this.

Comment: Did you try uploading the image via the link? If so, try uploading the image from your computer. I will migrate it once you get the image sorted out -- without the image there's probably not much a dev can do.

Comment: Done! Comment filler space.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't reproduce it, even when typing the exact question title, using Firefox as you show, etc. Is it still happening to you? Does it still happen if you turn off your extensions like AdBlock Plus (I think that's the icon), uBlock, etc.?

Comment: This was already asked on the main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340329/323179

Comment: FWIW, the mobile site defaults to just linking instead of uploading when providing a link.

Comment: Based on @Laurel's link, it seems prudent to ask what browser you're using etc?

Comment: Yep, I'm using Firefox too. Thanks for letting me know!